# Android Packaging Problem

Tags: android

i am using libgdx framework in android. i copied gdx-helloworld.zip from the link http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/list and imported it in eclipse. but the problem is i couldn't run the application.

Description - Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 Resource - gdx-helloworld-android Location - Unknown Type - Android Packaging Problem

I dont where is the problem. any pls help me solve the pbm

Comment: In Eclipse Settings, go to Android --> Build. Change "Build Output" to "Verbose" and try to build your app again. Hopefully you'll see more details about the offending classes. There is already a hint in your question: "Location - Unknown Type" but it is hard to figure out what "Location" class this is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

This preoblem is mostly due to Some Class with Same name and Same Package in your applications and libraries. do one thing, change package of your library to some other and then try to export the jar from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
1) Uncheck Build Automatically Option from Project menu .

2)manually  clean and build project.

Maybe this will solve your problem.

Note L its not for sure but my problem was resolved .
```